# More Efficient way to label axes in PGF Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I had been trying to label the x and y axes with every other tick mark and it took me a while to figure it out. I was able to, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to label the x-axes without having to put so many commas in the xticklabels. The code works the way I would like it to, just wanted to see if I could speed it up a little.

Also, is there a more efficient way to move the x and y-axis labels (seconds, feet per second)?  I don't like the cs: command either.

Thank you for your time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[thick,
    scale only axis,
    grid=major,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={-Triangle},
    xlabel={sec},
    ylabel={feet per second},
     x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,.20)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-.05,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
    ytick={-20,-10,...,50},
    xtick={0,1,...,16},
    xticklabels={,,2,,4,,6,,8,,10,,12,,14,,16,}, %MORE EFFICIENT OR EASIER WAY????
    ymin=-20,
    ymax=50,
    xmin=-.5,
    xmax=16,
]
\addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {(0,40) (8,0) (12,-20) (16,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is use of `grid=both, minor x tick num=1` and `xtick distance=2,ytick distance=10,`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[thick,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-Triangle},
    scale only axis,
%
    grid=both,
    minor x tick num=1,
%
    xlabel={sec},
    ylabel={feet per second},
%
    xmin=-.5,   xmax=16, xtick distance=2,
    ymin=-20,   ymax=50, ytick distance=10,
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0.2)},anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-.05,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
]

\addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {(0,40) (8,0) (12,-20) (16,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @zarko!!  This is great!

Comment: @NickB, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

By "the cs: command", you probably mean the `axis description cs:` coordinate system.

```
 x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,.20)},anchor=north},
```

is bad. It changes distance to the axis dependent on the limits -try to set `ymin=-100` to see it. Also `anchor=north` makes no sense as the vertical position is hard coded anyway. Use `xticklabel cs:` like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle, thick,
xmin=-.5, xmax=16,
ymin=-20, ymax=50,
xlabel={sec},
ylabel={feet per second},
x label style={at={(xticklabel cs:1)}, anchor=north},
ylabel near ticks,
y label style={anchor=center},
xtick distance=2,
minor x tick num=1,
ytick distance=10,
grid=both,
]
\addplot[red, ultra thick] coordinates {(0,40) (8,0) (12,-20) (16,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with a red plot, grid and labels]

Fine tuning of label positions can be done with `xshift` and `yshift` in the label styles.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with `tkz-base`

EDIT Indeed `tkz-euclide` is rather used in geometry; this package is not needed here.

```
\tkzDrawSegments[color=red,line width=1pt](A,B B,C)
```

can be replaced by

- `\draw[very thick,red](A)--(B)--(C);`  or
- `\draw[very thick,red] plot coordinates {(A) (B) (C)};`

We can insert `tikz` commands in `tkz-base`. For more complex functions, we can use `tkz-fct`.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673575/more-efficient-way-to-label-axes-in-pgf-plots
\usepackage{tkz-base}
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}%<-- for \tkzDrawSegments
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1.2]
    \tkzInit[
        xmax=16,xstep=2,
        ymin=-20,ymax=50,ystep=10
    ]
    \tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=1,subystep=10](0,-20)(16,50)
    %\tkzAxeXY
    \tkzDrawX[left space=0.25,label = sec,below = 15pt]
    \tkzLabelX[orig=false]
    %
    \tkzDrawY[label = feet per second,midway, above=30pt,sloped]
    \tkzLabelY[orig=false]
    %
    \tkzDefPoints{0/40/A,12/-20/B,16/0/C}
    \tkzDrawPoints[color=red,size=4pt](A,B,C)
    %\tkzDrawSegments[color=red,line width=1pt](A,B B,C)
    %\draw[very thick,red](A)--(B)--(C);
    \draw[very thick,red] plot coordinates {(A) (B) (C)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not as familiar with Tkz Euclide for plotting functions, more geometrical. Thank you!